# Number of records using normal joiner in informatica

Tags: sql, informatica-powercenter, joiner

I have a master table with one record:

```
employee Id
-----------
10
```

and detail table with 4 records:

```
employee Id1 
-----------
10
20
10
10
```

My join condition is `employee Id = employee Id1` with normal join type.

My question is which of the following output table will I get?

1. Output employee Id table with only 1 record (10)?

Or

2. Output employee Id table with 3 records (10, 10, 10)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Normal join type, output is 3 rows

**NORMAL JOIN** -It will give matching rows from both tables

**MASTER OUTER JOIN** - It will give matching rows from MASTER table and all rows from DETAIL table ,rest of the rows are discarded.

**DETAIL OUTER JOIN** - (just opposite above)
It will give matching rows from DETAIL table and all rows from MASTER Table.,rest of the rows are discarded.

Source with with fewer rows and with fewer duplicate keys should be consider as the master and the other source as detail.

Answer (score 1):

Output should be 3 records obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Your output will contains the 3 records which is satisfying the given condition